# ERROR Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm

I keep getting this error. I don't remember changing any part of the code it was working fine

```
Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null                                                       17:04:41  

  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules\extract-css-chunks-webpack-plugin\dist\CssDependency.js:12:46)
  at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
  at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
  at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules\extract-css-chunks-webpack-plugin\dist\index.js:14:45)
  at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
  at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
  at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
  at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules\extract-css-chunks-webpack-plugin\dist\cjs.js:3:18)
  at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
```

Comment: looks like a case of circular reference. Can you check the code and remove any extends references that might be extending into the class itself

Comment: @Tushar I reinstalled the webpack globally and now it's working ....Thank you for the response